# Can a RPi be network booted with an NFS other than NFSv3?

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, cmdline.txt, network-boot

Please excuse me if I am asking this question in the wrong place: I'm trying to network boot Ubuntu 22.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4B, and I'm not entirely clear where Raspberry ends and Ubuntu begins :-)

This activity is part of a longterm struggle I have taken up, not only to netboot Ubuntu on a Pi, but also to protect the root filesystem with `overlayroot`. To cut a long story short, netbooting works - `overlayroot` doesn't. The grisly [details are available here](https://superuser.com/questions/1716358/how-to-netboot-a-raspberry-pi-with-tftp-and-nfs-on-a-synology-nas) for anyone who is interested.

I am currently pursuing the hypothesis that `overlayroot` will not work if the the root filesystem is an NFSv3 mount. What I wanted to ask here is:

1. what is it that reads `cmdline.txt` and acts on *nfsroot=...*? (bootloader? something in Ubuntu? something else?)
2. can that something be realistically made to work with something other then NFSv3? (e.g. NFS 4 or 4.1)

I have tried various combinations of *(nfs)vers=4(.1)* in `cmdline.txt` but they either elicit complaints or have no effect.

Comment: Is there really no-one here who can answer this? Or is there somewhere more appropriate for me to ask this?

Comment: Raspberry OS can apparently boot from NFSv4. The Raspberry netboot documentation shows how.